# How to get parallax work in different section (one page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

How can I make parallax at different sections on an one page design and different positions of images?

Now I working with this code.

HTML markup:

```
<section class="highlights">
    <img src="images/hero.jpg" alt="" />
</section><!-- End section.highlights -->
```

The css of the image is

```
#hero, .highlights {
    height: 360px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.9;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 

    z-index:1;
}
#hero img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

The JS:

```
    $('#hero img').css({"bottom": '-' + $(window).scrollTop() / 2 + 'px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a JavaScript library such as Skrollr.js.

You will have a great control of your animations and the timing.

Check our these two tutorials to get you started with Skrollr:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)